# Context initialization failed while deploying the gwt application with spring framework

Tags: spring, gwt, jpa

Hi i was trying to integrate spring with jpa as the backend for the gwt client. Was tring to do it for the first time and am not able to make a way out this error

```
15:56:43,315 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'surevyDAOImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JPA PersistenceProvider returned null EntityManagerFactory - check your JPA provider setup!
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JPA PersistenceProvider returned null EntityManagerFactory - check your JPA provider setup!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findNamedEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:510)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JPA PersistenceProvider returned null EntityManagerFactory - check your JPA provider setup!
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 45 more
```

I have been using the following files:
web.xml:

```
<!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>MobiOffer_GWT.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
     <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>rest-json-api</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>rest-json-api</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/restServices/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>gwtDispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.gwtrpcspring.RemoteServiceDispatcher</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>gwtDispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/mobioffer_gwt/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I rest-json-api-servlet.xml file which is refered by the above web.xml file is:

```
 <!-- auto scan annotations -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.reva.mobioffer.services"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />


    <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>

    <bean class="com.reva.mobioffer.views.MyContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"/>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.reva.mobioffer.views.JSONView"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I was also using applicationContext.xml file but i was not sure what exactly is the use of this xml file( i could see that the jpa information is mentioned through it)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.reva.mobioffer.domain"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mobioffer"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
            <value>classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceAnnotation"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"
            />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

this was also throwing me an exception as cannot create the bean for org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0

the persistance.xml file is located in the META-INF file:

```
<persistence-unit name="mobioffer" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.Survey</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyLog</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyLogPK</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyQuestion</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyQuestionOptionMap</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyQuestionOptionMapPK</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyQuestionOption</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyQuestionOptionPK</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyQuestionResponse</class>
        <class>com.reva.mobioffer.domain.entity.SurveyQuestionResponsePK</class>

                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:4406/mobioffer" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

i have been stuck with it since quite a while but could not find a way to resolve it even after a extreme search.
Thanks

Comment: Are the Spring JARs and the config files all in your `WEB-INF/lib` (or `WEB-INF/classes`)? Are they also in the DevMode classpath? Try removing them from the classpath so they only exist within the `WEB-INF`.

Comment: Turn on debug logging for spring. And if you can't figure out, then post the logs.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the exception:

> JPA PersistenceProvider returned null EntityManagerFactory - check your JPA provider setup!

It looks like your JPA isn't properly setup.  I would start by making sure you can connect to the MySQL DB from the device you are running this on.  MySQL has granular security to the point that it can lock down users based on the host/ip they are coming from.  Also make sure the user has access to the database.

Second, I would make sure I spelled all the DB names, user name, etc right.  Again, the exception is coming from the JPA setup, so start there.